# Sending and receiving all data (C++ sockets)

Tags: c++, sockets

Help me please to find out what is wrong in client-server communication...

The client sends to server jpeg frames from camera 25 times per second using this function:

```
int SendAll(SOCKET &client_socket, string &data){
    int result, bytes_sent, sent_total, bytes_remain, package_size;
    result = bytes_sent = sent_total = package_size = 0;
    bytes_remain = data.size();
    while (bytes_remain && !result){
        package_size = (bytes_remain<KILOBYTE)?bytes_remain:KILOBYTE;
        bytes_sent = send(client_socket, &data[sent_total], package_size, 0);
        if (bytes_sent > 0){
            bytes_remain-= bytes_sent;
            sent_total+= bytes_sent;
        }
        else if(bytes_sent == SOCKET_ERROR){
            result = WSAGetLastError();
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In thread loop:

```
while(CAMERA.Stream){
    OperationStartTime = GetTickCount();
    //RecvBuffer.resize(512);
    result = SendAll(CAMERA.Socket, CameraFrame);
    if(result != 0){
        cout << "error in send - " << result;
        CAMERA.Stream = false;
        break;
    }
    if (recv(CAMERA.Socket, &RecvBuffer, 1, 0) < 0){
        CAMERA.Stream = false;
        break;
    }  
    while(OperationStartTime + StreamRate > GetTickCount()){
        if (!CAMERA.Stream){break;}
        Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Sometimes I see "error in send - 10053" (testing on localhost)

Server uses this function to receive all data:

```
int RecvAll(SOCKET &client_socket, string &data){
    data = "";
    int bytes_received = 0;
    int result = 0;
    char* recv_buffer;
    do {
        recv_buffer = (char*)malloc(KILOBYTE);
        bytes_received = recv(client_socket, recv_buffer, KILOBYTE, 0);
        if (bytes_received > 0){
            data.append(recv_buffer, bytes_received);
            if (bytes_received < KILOBYTE || data.size() >= 512*KILOBYTE){
                bytes_received = result = 0;}
        }
        else if(bytes_received == SOCKET_ERROR){
            data.clear();
            result = WSAGetLastError();
        }
        free(recv_buffer);
    }
    while (bytes_received > 0);
    return result;
}
```

And no errors on server side.

What is wrong in `SendAll`  and `RecvAll` functions and how to acheivea stabile data transfering?

*PS: and sometimes client stops, and only reconnecting helps. But if to reconnect, the server shows one more socket connected - it means that CAMERA.Socket was block and I don't understand why*

Comment: Are you asking us to debug your program for you?

Comment: Have you tried looking up that error code?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, not to debug at all, but maybe somebody will see something wrong in logic

Comment: @AndrewHenle, yes - seems the problem is in client. Can't figure out is server has effect on it

Comment: I don't comprehend the distinction, Iceman.

Comment: try the simplest things first:  slow down the transfer rate...control frame size to uniform small frame...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The client is not sending the data size to the server so it knows how many bytes to actually read for each frame being sent.

It is also not handling the case where the server disconnects, or handling the `StreamRate` calculation correctly, either.

Try something more like this instead:

Client:

```
int SendAll(SOCKET client_socket, const void *data, int data_size)
{
    const char *data_ptr = (const char*) data;
    int bytes_sent;

    while (data_size > 0)
    {
        bytes_sent = send(client_socket, data__ptr, data_size, 0);
        if (bytes_sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
            return -1;

        data_ptr += bytes_sent;
        data_size -= bytes_sent;
    }

    return 1;
}

int SendAll(SOCKET client_socket, const string &data)
{
    ulong data_size = htonl(data.size());

    int result = SendAll(client_socket, &data_size, sizeof(data_size));
    if (result == 1)
        result = SendAll(client_socket, data.c_str(), data.size());

    return result;
}

...

int result;
char reply;

while (CAMERA.Stream)
{
    OperationStartTime = GetTickCount();

    result = SendAll(CAMERA.Socket, CameraFrame);
    if (result != 1)
    {
        cout << "error in send - " << WSAGetLastError();
        CAMERA.Stream = false;
        break;
    }

    result = recv(CAMERA.Socket, &reply, 1, 0);
    if (result <= 0)
    {
        if (result == 0)
            cout << "server disconnected";
        else
            cout << "error in read - " << WSAGetLastError();

        CAMERA.Stream = false;
        break;
    }  

    while (CAMERA.Stream && ((GetTickCount() - OperationStartTime) < StreamRate))
    {
        Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Server:

```
int RecvAll(SOCKET client_socket, void *data, int data_size)
{
    char *data_ptr = (char*) data;
    int bytes_recv;

    while (data_size > 0)
    {
        bytes_recv = recv(client_socket, data_ptr, data_size, 0);
        if (bytes_recv <= 0)
            return bytes_recv;

        data_ptr += bytes_sent;
        data_size -= bytes_sent;
    }

    return 1;
}

int RecvAll(SOCKET client_socket, string &data)
{
    ulong data_size;
    int result;

    data = "";

    result = RecvAll(client_socket, &data_size, sizeof(data_size));
    if (result == 1)
    {
        data_size = ntohl(data_size);
        if (data_size > 0)
        {
            data.resize(data_size);

            result = RecvAll(client_socket, &data[0], data_size);
            if (result != 1)
                data.clear();
        }
    }

    return result;
}

...

string data;
int result;
char reply;

while (true)
{
    result = RecvAll(socket, data);
    if (result != 1)
    {
        if (read == 0)
            cout << "client disconnected";
        else
            cout << "error in read - " << WSAGetLastError();

        break;
    }

    // process data as needed...

    reply = 1;
    if (send(socket, &reply, 1, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "error in send - " << WSAGetLastError();
        break;
    }
}
```